# Excel VBA select every other cell

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say we have text in A4, C4, E4, G4, I4, K4, etc. (every other cell going right)

I'd like a macro to operate on the selections "A5:B5" if there is text in A4, "C5:D5" if there is text in C4 etc, and to stop once the corresponding cell in row 4 is not present.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Try by "translating" what you just typed into pseudocode. After that we will help you setup it for VBA.

Comment: The question seems fairly straight forward... I don't really see a need for pseudocode...

Comment: I don't understand your question...please see the [help-centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't understand either. What do you mean by "operate"? I suggest you edit your question, rewriting it from scratch. Show us example input and desired output, and what you have tried to get this desired output. Don't tell; show.

Comment: The body of the loop is irrelevant... I'm only asking how I'd go about making the loop in the first place. The operation has nothing to do with this question, and as such, I did not include it.

Comment: Agreed, this question is badly phrased / asked, but to give you something to start off with, if I understand what you want - Look into `For ... Step 2` loops to look at every other column and the `OFFSET()` vba function to move away from you current cell... But if you rephrase the question and show us what you've tried maybe we can be of even better help than that....

Comment: @JohnBustos thanks, that's exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
For i = 1 To 9999 Step 2
    If Cells(4, i).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Cells(5, i).Value = Cells(4, i).Value * 2
    Cells(5, i + 1).Value = Cells(4, i).Value / 2
Next
```

The code use the value in row 4 and 1st **Value*2** and 2nd **Value/2**.